# input a txt file with bunch of number in every row

Tags: java, arrays, function

Hi i have a txt file that have a number in bunch of rows and i get this error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

what can i add in my code to make it work it seems to be right to me but idont know why i get error

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input;
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("andy.txt"));
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                lineCounters++;
                input = scan.nextLine();
                putArray(sigFig(input));
            }
            calcPercentage();
            makeGraph();
            scan.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

here is my putArray

```
public static void putArray(char input) {

        switch (input) {
            case '1':
                ++digitCounters[0];
                break;
            case '2':
                ++digitCounters[1];
                break;
            case '3':
                ++digitCounters[2];
                break;
            case '4':
                ++digitCounters[3];
                break;
            case '5':
                ++digitCounters[4];
                break;
            case '6':
                ++digitCounters[5];
                break;
            case '7':
                ++digitCounters[6];
                break;
            case '8':
                ++digitCounters[7];
                break;
            case '9':
                ++digitCounters[8];
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should tell which line throws the exception and then add the code of specific method (if there is) that throws it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be your putArray function which launches that exception. Can I have a look of it?

Comment: Upload your sigFig function and an example of input file.